# How do you implement __delitem__ when subclassing collections.MutableSequence?

Tags: python

Using Alex Martelli's guidance to use collections.MutableSequence instead of subclassing list() (using Python 2.6.6)

Alex suggested using

```
class HostList(collections.MutableSequence):
    """A container for manipulating lists of hosts"""
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the class"""
        self.list = list()
```

I *must* implement `__delitem__`, or MutableSequence gets cranky...

```
>>> import HostList as H
>>> foo = H.HostList()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class HostList with abstract methods __delitem__
>>>
```

I have also tried to build `__delitem__` with `return del(ii)` and `return self.list.remove(ii)`... but none of those worked.  What is the right way to declare `__delitem__` in this context?

**EDIT: The final resolution was doing this**

```
    def __delitem__(self, ii):
        """Delete an item"""
        del self.list[ii]    # Thank you @Thomas for the pointer about .remove()
        return
```

Comment: In case the comment in the accepted answer wasn't clear: you should really use `del self.list[ii]` instead of `self.list.remove(self.list[ii])`; the latter is far less efficient, and it can remove *the wrong item* when the item appears multiple times in the list.

Comment: definivly you should use `del self.list[ii]` as it avoid you to lookup the list to find the same item and abviously it would not not do the wrong thing on calling `del l[2]` with `l like ['a','b','a']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`del ii`, `del(ii)` : you are deleting the name `ii` from the scope of the function `__delitem__`, not the list (see: [`del`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement))

If `ii` is an item in the list, you can use: `self.list.remove(ii);`

If ii is an index of an item in the list, you can use: `self.list.remove(self.list[ii])`

### Update

Or as *@Thomas Wouters* said, its better to use `del self.list[ii]`

Comment: That doesn't work... if I use `list.remove(ii)`, python throws `TypeError: descriptor 'remove' requires a 'list' object but received a 'int'`.  I went down the `.remove()` road before I posted the question... no-worky so far

Comment: you can also use del self.list[ii]

Comment: @Mike that's the problem with using builtin names yous should use self.list.remove(ii)

Comment: It does that because `list` is the name for the class, and you're not overruling it in local scope, or referencing it appropiately. You're calling an instance method, passing as first parameter an int: you're assigning an `int` to the `self` parameter, that is, when the list class expects, well, a list.

Comment: there was a missing `self` in (self.list.remove(ii);) in my answer. How did you write the `remove`?

Comment: @Xavier and @manji... when I use `self.list.remove(ii)`, I get `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`.  I am posting the an edit with the contents of my unit test above...

Comment: if `ii` is an index of an item in the list, try: `self.list.remove(self.list[ii])`

Comment: @manji, `self.list.remove(self.list[ii])` works... +2 for your efforts.  Thank you!

Comment: Not only *can* you use `del self.list[ii]`, you really should. It's far less roundabout, less inefficient and won't do the wrong thing.